# What are these pieces of cooking equipment called?

Tags: nouns, terminology, image-identification

I decided to write down all the recipes I know to my website in English. However, I realized that I do not know what many common items are called. To make things even more confusing, I do not know if all the foods (or the equipment to prepare them) even exist in English-speaking countries. I have found various translations, but they do not seem to be very exact and it remains unclear what kind of an item I am speaking of.

How should I call these items so that it is clear what I'm talking about?

Item 1: glass or metal, diameter about 24-30cm. Height about 5cm. Used to bake salty or sweet pies (or at least we would call it a pie).

[image: pie-baking item]

Item 2: metal, used to bake sweet... cakes? that are dry. Diameter about 25cm.

[image: dry cake thing]

Item 3: metal, used to bake sweet cakes that are not dry. Diameter varies, usually between 20 and 30cm. Removable bottom.

[image: cake-baking item]

Item 4: usually glass, used to bake a variety of foods (not pies or cakes) in the oven.

[image: glass baking thing]

Comment: It looks like you got satisfactory answers this time (possibly because these are somewhat common pieces of cookware.)  It might be better to ask on https://cooking.stackexchange.com when you have less common items. And if you have such nice images, you can probably do a reverse image search on google to get an idea what they are called.

Comment: You are right. I also tried the reverse image search for some of these, but I only got results in Finnish (even though the language is set to English). Maybe this is because I got the pictures from various Finnish online shops.

Comment: Also note that terminology for foods, equipment, techniques, and measurements also varies within the English-language world, e.g. [over-easy eggs](/questions/411758), [grilling vs. broiling](/questions/345769), and so forth. See *[Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA / NZ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784)* at our sister site, Seasoned Advice.

Comment: @choster: I was thinking that OP may very well have asked this question on Seasoned Advice.

Comment: I think the answers below are American. In UK I would call 1 a pie dish, 3 a cake tin, 4 an oven dish. Don't know what 2 is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

American here. These are the terms I would know them by:

1. Pie Pan (metal)/pie dish (glass)
2. Bundt cake pan
3. Springform pan
4. Baking dish

Comment: You beat me to it. All of these are correct.

Comment: #4 might also be called a "casserole dish".

Comment: I  (British) would call #1 a _flan dish_, and speak of a cake _tin_.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, specifically #1 is a flan dish, #2 is a ring mould and #3 is a spring-form cake tin. However #4 could be one of a number of things depending on its function at any given time. I've used mine for cakes, pudfings, lasagne and bread before now but to me its a deep oblong glass dish!

Answer (score 2):

1. Tart form. A pie plate/dish/pan has a flat bottom and sloping sides. Common sizes are 9 and 10 inches. Your dish has an indentation designed to hold fruit or other filling in the finished baked good. You can't bake a pie in one of these. Believe me, I’ve tried.

This is a Pyrex pie plate:

[image]

2. The closest you'll get to a Guglhupf pan in English is a Bundt pan, but those are often not as tall. There are some gelatin molds (AmE)/jelly moulds (BrE) closer to this shape.
3. Springform (cake) pan.
4. Glass bread (or loaf) pan.